# preview stretches when start video recording

Tags: java, android, camera, mediarecorder, textureview

I'm trying to make a custom camera activity. Everything works great until the MediaRecorder starts recording a video. The preview stretches horizontally without an obvious reason as below. I have tried changing the preview size and several suggestions but I couldn't find a working solution. Any Ideas please !!

note: I'm using TextureView object.

preview before recording
[image: preview before recording]

preview while recording
[image: preview while recording]

start camera

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    mST = surface;
    try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mST);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        isReleased = false;
    }catch(Exception e){}
    //startVideoPreview();
}
```

start media recorder

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(camId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_HIGH));
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000); //set maximum duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); //set maximum file size 50M
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tempVid.mp4");



    if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    }else{
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    }
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

thank you so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171009/6490462

Comment: @Ibrahim I tried it. but it didn't work.

Comment: Really? I would believe that https://i.stack.imgur.com/erj5z.png looks correct, while https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whzt4.png is distorted...

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your app.

One, you should choose preview size that suits you. Your code in **onSurfaceTextureAvailable()** relies on default, which is too optimistic. Some devices have weird defaults for preview size. Especially when you want live preview displayed on a surface. You should choose the optimal preview size (from the list returned by [Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes())). The optimal size will be the best to fit the given width and height. The most important factor is *aspect ratio*. But also, you also want the preview not to be too small or too big. You can pick up a simple example of [getBestPreviewSize ()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775898/192373).

The second issue is that MediaRecorder also sets the 'preview' size. Each CamcorderProfile defines a specific frame size, and when you choose it, the live preview on your screen changes accordingly. You can override this with [MediaRecorder.setVideoSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoSize(int,%20int)), but if this size does not fit the chosen CamcorderProfile, your recording may be spoiled.

Not all supported preview sizes may be used for video recording, (see [Parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes())). So, if you open preview with intention to record video, you should choose an optimal preview size that can be used by MediaRecorder, and make sure you set both Camera and MediaRecorder this way.

Finally, note that you are working with a *deprecated* Camera API. If your target device is Lollipop and above, consider switching to [**camera2**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API.

Comment: I'm going to try this solution and I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: After some attempts I was able to make it better but not as expected. I did that by setting the video size when initializing the MediaRecorder but it still expands but just a little bit.

Comment: What sizes do you use now?